# Cant I get rid of fmt prefix when calling Println in Golang

Tags: go

I tried http://tour.golang.org/#1

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    Println("Hello World")
}
```

This generates error :

```
prog.go:3: imported and not used: "fmt"
prog.go:6: undefined: Println
 [process exited with non-zero status]

Program exited
```

Does it mean I am obliged to prefix Println with "fmt" package name ? In other languages it isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to prefix a function if it is not in the current package.

What you can do however is create an alias for this package:

```
import f "fmt"

func main() {
    f.Println("Hello World")
}
```

Or *"rename"* the function:

```
import "fmt"

var Println = fmt.Println

func main() {
    Println("Hello World")
}
```

Or use `.` as alias (it may be what you would like most):

```
import . "fmt"

func main() {
    Println("Hello World")
}
```

Note that in that case, the alias is not blank. From the [specifications](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers) of Go:

> A qualified identifier is an identifier qualified with a package name prefix. Both the package name and the identifier must not be blank.
>
> `QualifiedIdent = PackageName "." identifier .`

And another example from the same [specifications](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations):

```
import   "lib/math"         math.Sin
import m "lib/math"         m.Sin
import . "lib/math"         Sin
```

Comment: and there is one more: the "_" alias

Comment: The `_` prefix cannot be used in this case: if you import a package anonymously, you won't be able to call any of its functions. Its only purpose is to call indirectly the `init` function of the package (and possibly other things that I did not think about).

Comment: I should note that it's *not* good practice to alias the standard library. It makes your code less readable to others for the sake of three (!) characters. Use [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) for autocompletion if you want to save your fingers.