# How to export a name so that it becomes globally accessible?

Tags: go

I want to export a function from my package so that I can use it without typing a package name before it, how to do that?

```
import "mypackage"

func main() {
   mypackage.myfunc()    <-- that's what I have already
   myfunc()              <-- that's what I need
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant I get rid of fmt prefix when calling Println in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822826/cant-i-get-rid-of-fmt-prefix-when-calling-println-in-golang)

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the followings:

```
import (  
    .     "mypackage"                           // without a name  
    mp    "my/other/package"                    // rename
    _     "my/totally/diffrent/package"         // import a package solely for its side-effects (initialization)
)
```

Obviously, this pattern is not recommended since it can cause name conflicts with other packages.

[Check out the dot imports bulletin](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat)